# linux makefile help declaring FC FFLAGS variable based on make gnu or make linux rule

Tags: linux, variables, makefile

I'm trying to modify my Makefile such that i can type either

"make gnu" or "make intel"

and it will compile everything with the only difference being

FC = gfortran-4.8  or  ifort,
and
FFLAGS = appropriate flags for gfortran or ifort.

can someone help with what i have so far?

```
SOURCES = a1.f a2.f a3.f
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.f=.o)
TARGET = myexececutable.x

gnu: GNU_FC $(TARGET)

intel: INTEL_FC $(TARGET)

GNU_FC:
    FC = gfortran-4.8
    FFLAGS = -O3 -mcmodel=medium -shared

INTEL_FC:
    FC = ifort
    FFLAGS = -O3 -mcmodel medium -shared-intel

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)

.f.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $*.f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for **MAKECMDGOALS**.

Here below I had roughly modified your Makefile , Please check below : -

```
SOURCES = a1.f a2.f a3.f
    OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.f=.o)
    TARGET = myexececutable.x

    gnu: GNU_FC $(TARGET)

    intel: INTEL_FC $(TARGET)

    ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),gnu)
    GNU_FC:
        FC = gfortran-4.8
        FFLAGS = -O3 -mcmodel=medium -shared
    endif

    ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),intel)
    INTEL_FC:
        FC = ifort
        FFLAGS = -O3 -mcmodel medium -shared-intel
    endif

    $(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)

    .f.o:
        $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $*.f
```

More information can be got here

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html][1]

Answer (score 1):

thanks.  i got it to work as i wanted based on your MAKECMDGOALS help.
here's my makefile and it works pretty good.
if you type just makefile with no arguments then it executes the all: section and stops, which is good because it forces the user to explicity state whether to use the gnu compiler or the intel compiler... or whatever else.

```
COMPILER_VERSION = "Intel 64 Compiler 16.0 and gfortran-4.8"

SOURCES = \
program1.f \
program2.f \
program3.f

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.f=.o)
TARGET = ../lib/mylib.a

all:
       @echo ""
       @echo "   type either     make intel     or     make gnu"
       @echo ""

intel: INTEL_FC linux
gnu:   GNU_FC linux

ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),intel)
  INTEL_FC:
    FC = ifort
    FFLAGS = -O3 -integer-size 64 -real-size 64 -align -pad -mcmodel medium -shared-intel
endif

ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),gnu)
  GNU_FC:
    FC = gfortran-4.8
    FFLAGS = -O3 -falign-commons -finit-local-zero -fdefault-integer-8 -fdefault-real-8 -mcmodel=medium -shared -fopenmp
endif

linux: ECHO1 $(TARGET)
        @echo
        @echo -n "   "
        ar r $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
        @echo
        @echo -n "   "
        ranlib $(TARGET)
        @echo

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)

.f.o:
        @echo -n "   "
        $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $*.f

cleanall:
        @echo
        rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)
        @echo

clean:
        @echo
        rm -f $(OBJECTS)
        @echo

ECHO1:
        @echo
        @echo "   Makefile written for the compiler version ${COMPILER_VERSION}"
        @echo
```